# Way to collapse results in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Ive been trying to find out how to get the results from my code into a window that you can then collapse so they dont take up the whole document. Basically turning the results into a drop down list that the viewer can open and close.

New to Markdown, Have not tried many things yet

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

R-markdown in this scenario works exactly like markdown. Use the following snippet to add a dropdown.

```
<summary>Title</summary>
<br>
Body
</details>
```